# Is there a limit for data MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm working on a script to push data into MySQL workbench. While exploring the workbench, I saw there is this option which says "Limit to 50000 rows" and it can be changed from Don't Limit to 50000. Is this just to limit the data/row being displayed for each table, or it will only store 50000 rows for each table ? Is there a limit to the data or row being stored for each table? Or as long as my hard disk size is sufficient it will keep saving the data. Also is there a way to check how much size each table is ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The limit only applies to what is displayed. It doesn't affect the underlying data.

Comment: @KenWhite so there's no limit for the data/rows ? Till my storage runs out ? Is there a way to view the amount of data used ? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, there's no limit to the underlying data. It applies only to what's displayed. `COUNT(*)` displays the number of rows in your table itself.

Answer (score 0):

This limit option simply applies a `LIMIT` clause to queries which support it (unless the user has already added such a clause).

This is a simple measure to help new users to avoid the common pitfall of running a `SELECT` on a large data set unconditionally. More advanced users usually disable this option and manually apply a `LIMIT` clause where needed.